# Expresión regular para evitar que un input solo contenga espacios en blanco?

Tags: javascript, regex, formularios

Tengo un formulario validado, salvo por 1 detalle, en mi campo nombre, el usuario no puede dejarlo vacío, y debe escribir al menos 3 caracteres para ser un campo válido, si eso no se cumple, a la hora de dar a enviar el formulario, se hará focus en este campo junto con un mensaje de error indicando el propio error.

El caso es que si el usuario escribe 3 espacios en blanco y le da a enviar, la validación que tengo planteada se lo come y el formulario se envía con un nombre vacío técnicamente.

Estaba pensando en crear una expresión regular que lo que haga sea cuando hay al menos 2 o más espacios en blanco juntos, reemplazarlo por 1 solo espacio, de esta forma, la cadena de texto por muchos espacios que tuviese juntos, se reemplazarían por 1 solo, y no cumpliría la validación previa de 3 o más caracteres.

Lo pensé de esta forma para que no hubiese conflictos si el usuario escribía su nombre compuesto, en este caso al haber únicamente 1 solo espacio entre palabras, no ocurre nada.

He intentado hacer algo como:

```
if (c_nombre.value.length >= 3){

    c_nombre.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
}
```

Donde la variable c_nombre apunta al input en cuestión, y c_nombre.value apunta al valor de ese input.

Por si queréis ver el código completo de mi validación para tener más contexto os lo dejo aquí

```
    var formu = document.forms[0];
    var c_nombre= formu.nombre;
    var info_error = document.createElement("p");
    var text_name_empty = document.createTextNode("Por favor rellene el campo");
    var allcampoDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".campo");

 //Validar campo nombre
    if (c_nombre.value == ""||c_nombre.value.length<3){
        
        c_nombre.focus();
        c_nombre.classList.toggle("campoError");
        c_nombre.addEventListener("input", function(){
            if (c_nombre.value.length>=3){
                c_nombre.className="";
            }
        })
        if(c_nombre.value == ""){
            info_error.appendChild(text_name_empty);   
        }
        else if(c_nombre.value.length<4){
            var text_name_length = document.createTextNode("El nombre debe contener más de 3 letras");
            info_error.appendChild(text_name_length);
           
           
        }   
        allcampoDiv[0].before(info_error);
        allcampoDiv[0].addEventListener("change", function(){
            info_error.style.display="none";
        })
        return;
    }
    else{
        if (c_nombre.value.length >= 3){
            c_nombre.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
        }
        c_nombre.className="";  
    }
```

Pero de alguna forma al presionar el botón de enviar se lo sigue comiendo, no lo tengo bien planteado creo. ¿Se os ocurre algo?

Comment: ( +){2}  Detecta 2 ó mas espacios en blanco juntos.

Comment: hola @josephl no sería el mismo caso de lo que tengo ya escrito?

Comment: Y no te has planteado usar [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) sobre el valor del `input` en vez de acudir a una regex?

Comment: El problema con usar trim es que si el nombre es compuesto como Juan Jesús, se cortan los espacios del principio y final de cadena, pero si se ponen 2 o más espacios  entre palabras, trim( ) no va a solucionar eso. De ahí lo de una expresión regular, que siempre que vea 2 o más espacios en blanco, reemplazarlo por 1 espacio solo. De hecho lo propio sería usar las 2 cosas, trim para quitar espacios a principios y final de cadena, y la expresión regular para reemplazarlos. Tengo que ver como planteo algo así.

Answer (score 2):

Este ejemplo elimina los espacios en blanco delante y detrás del texto.

```js
var input = "     nombre      "
output = input.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/ +$/, "")
console.log("_"+output+"_")
```

Equivalentemente:

```js
var input = "     nombre      "
output = input.trim()
console.log("_"+output+"_")
```

Luego chequeas la longitud sobre la nueva variable y listo.

Comment: Hola hice ```  var c_nombre_output = c_nombre.value.trim(); ``` y con su correspondiente check de longitud, se valida bien ahora pero no sé por qué el nombre que el formulario envía es con espacios, por ejemplo hice una prueba con: "      test     test"  y ese nombre pasa la validación y me llega al correo con los espacios, cuando deberían estar quitados no? no sé si me he explicado bien.

Comment: @JuanJesús entonces tu `input` debe aceptar sólo una palabra. ¿Es lo que quieres validar? Y que la misma tenga al menos 3 caracteres.

Comment: @MauricioContreras mi input puede y debe aceptar varias palabras por si el nombre es compuesto, con la última respuesta de joseph ya sé plantear esto, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Input que solo acepta un espacio entre letras y al perder foco remueve espacio al principio y al final:

```js
function removerEspacios() {
       return  document.getElementById("nombre").value.replace(/(  +)/g, ' ');
}

function finalizar(){
        return document.getElementById("nombre").value.trim();
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="nombre" oninput="this.value = removerEspacios();" onblur="this.value = finalizar()"/>
```

*En parte con el aporte de Ric Villalba

Comment: Me gusta, me has dado una idea para solucionar este problemilla, gracias Joseph  ^^